# How to unzip all files in sub-directories?

Tags: linux

I have a folder named `data`, inside this folder there are sub-folders, in these sub-folders I have the compressed files.

I tried to unzip one file and succeed using:

```
tar -xvzf file.tgz
```

Now I want to unzip all files in `data`. Any hints on this?

I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name '*.tgz' -exec tar -xvzf {} \;
```

other methods here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50313/how-do-i-perform-an-action-on-all-files-with-a-specific-extension-in-subfolders

Comment: Would suggest your find would be best limited to `-name '*.tgz'`.

Comment: Good catch, added the option